# How to choose PWM frequency?

Tags: pwm, frequency

I got an article on this [link](http://www.eprojectszone.com/how-to-generate-a-sine-wave-from-arduino-or-atmega-328/). In this article the author chooses a PWM frequency of 31,372 Hz to get a smooth signal.

How do these frequency values get a smooth signal?

I've read other articles on the website but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The cutoff frequency of the lowpass filter you are using determines how low a frequency you can use and still have it be smooth. But your cutoff frequency places an upper limit on how quickly the output signal can respond. So if your cutoff frequency was 1kHz, you aren't going to be able to produce a 100kHz signal. You will probably only get to choose your filter if this is a DAC. If this is a power application like a motor, then the filter has already been chosen for you (the motor inductance).

If this is not just a DAC and you are actually driving a lot of current with the PWM, then you can't use too high a frequency either because this increases switching losses and will overheat your switches.

Answer (score 0):

[image: wikipedia]

Image source: wikipedia

The above wave is generated by PWM. As you see from above image the analog wave have lot of whipsaw blade like pattern, in simple terms as you increase the frequency the whipsaw pattern will get shorter, which in turn smooth the wave form, based on the frequency and filter technique used to smooth the waveform we can achieve almost near perfect waveform

[Pulse-width modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to PWM an inductive load then you'd have to look at the inductance and how much current ripple you want to design in to choose the PWM frequency.

In the case of this article though, the author just wants to output a sine signal at frequency F. So he uses PWM at frequency Fs.

Ideally we want Fs to be much above F for these two reasons:

1. The PWM has to be low-pass filtered to turn the square wave into a smooth sine. Higher Fs gives better filtering and allows a lower order filter. Sampling theory says Fs has to be at least double frequency F, but that assumes a perfect sinc analog filter which is impossible to make. To get a smooth signal with a simple first order RC filter, Fs must be much higher. In engineering terms: there is a cost and complexity compromise between the analog filter order and the sampling frequency. Since it is cheaper to use a higher frequency than to add a N-th order filter with a ton of opamps, then let's raise the frequency.
2. Each PWM cycle outputs a digital to analog sample. We want enough samples per cycle of our sine so it still looks like a sine. With 4 samples per period, unless we have a perfect sinc filter, the sine will look like a square with the edges rounded off by RC exponential decay.

...but Fs can't be too high because:

1. It's a PWM, so the number of distinct values each PWM sample can have is equal to the clock frequency used by the timer divided by the PWM period. If we have 16MHz clock and a period of 16 cycles, we can have Fs=2 MHz, but we have only 16 output levels, ie a 4-bit DAC. So the sine will look jaggy unless dithering is applied.
2. Something will have to load each sample value into the timer, once per cycle. If the micro has DMA that can be fast. If it doesn't, that will be an interrupt, so Fs is limited to the max interrupt rate. Also you'll need some memory to store the values, etc.

So, wet finger in the breeze, pick a compromise, 32 kHz, why not.

Note if the chip creates the timer clock with an integer divider from its main clock, then it will have to be an integer ratio. So you can't get exactly all frequencies, so pick the closest.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the chosen frequency is arrived through several considerations.

The first is that the microprocessor and the libraries used in the project can conveniently generate the frequency.  The code is using values from a formula given in the datasheet of the processor.  Since it all has to work with 8bit or 16 bits values and the processor clock runs at a particular frequency, only certain frequencies are possible.  You couldn't, for example, easily hit 31380.  31372 is a frequency that is easily generated using the given timers and clock frequency.

The second consideration is the signal to be generated.  To get a smooth representation of a sine wave, you need to generate a lot of points in the wave.  [The Nyquist criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) says you need at least twice as many points per second as the signal you want to generate.  It also says you need a low pass reconstruction filter for that to work properly.  In reality, it is better to generate a lot of points for your signal.  The example  generates 314 points for a 50Hz wave.  That's 15500 points per second.

Finally, you have the low pass filter.  The example is using a simple RC filter to remove the high frequency PWM signal from the output signal.  Those filters aren't very effective, so you have to set the cutoff very low (far below the PWM frequency) to clean up the output.  The circuit given uses a 47 ohm resistor with a 22µF capacitor.  That's a cutoff of 153 Hz.  That's high enough not to attenuate the generated 50Hz sine wave, but at 31372 Hz it will attenuate the PWM by about 24dB.  That's enough that you don't really see the PWM frequency in the output.

---

The correct way to figure out the required PWM frequency would be to start at the end result and work backwards.

You would specify the output frequency and how pure it has to be - the allowed limits for harmonics of the generated signal frequency and allowed limits for the PWM frequency that can be present in the output signal.

From the allowed harmonics you would figure out how many steps per second and at what voltage resolution you have to have to keep the harmonics below the limit.

From the limit for the amount of PWM frequency allowed to be in the signal, you can figure out how much higher than the signal frequency the PWM frequency has to be.  With a better filter, you can either get a cleaner output or you can use a lower PWM frequency.  This is always a compromise.  Better filters are more complicated, but the processor has limits on how high the PWM freqeuncy can be.  You have to reach a compromise where the processor can generate the required PWM frequency (at the needed resolution) but where the output filter can still be easily made.

You may have to repeatedly change and calculate to see what gives you the best compromise.

---

Practically, hobbyists pick an easy to generate high PWM frequency, build an output filter with a cutoff close to the final signal output frequency, and hope for the best.

The circuits are easy enough to build that a few minutes building and trying it out will be faster than endless rounds of math.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following:

1. You want the highest PWM frequency possible, because the PWM will have to be filtered in hardware (They use a RC filter in the article). The filter's cutoff frequency (-3dB) will have to be chosen so that it allows the modulated signal (the 50Hz sine) to pass trough, while attenuating the carrier (the PWM) as much as possible . So, say we choose a RC filter with a cutoff point at 200Hz, it's bode plot will look like this: (plot generated by [Okawa electric design RC Low-pass Filter Design Tool](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRlowkeisan.htm))

[image]

You can see that the filter starts attenuating a bit above 50Hz and that it requires 20kHz before reaching 40dB attenuation (1/100th). So even if the PWM was at 20Khz there'd still be 1% of the PWM signal present in the output. At 30kHz we do slightly better.

2. They use the "Phase correct hardware PWM" feature of the Atmel AVR controller on the Arduino on Timer 0. Timer 0 is a 8-bit timer, which means it can count from 0-255. In Phase correct PWM the timer counts up from 0 towards the TOP value (255), then it reverses direction and counts down again towards 0, then the cycle repeats. Since the Arduino runs on 16MHz, we get:

16000000 / (255 + 255) = 31372,... Hz.

So, basically 31372 is the fastest phase correct PWM with 8-bit resolution that can be achieved with a 16MHz clock on this AVR.

You can select a diffirent TOP value, lower then 255, which would increase the PWM frequency but would decrease the resolution.

Comment: Since the article mentions both DACs and inverters, I think it is misleading to say you want the highest frequency possible. For a signal application like a DAC where you are not transmitting power, you want the highest frequency you can get away with to maximize signal fidelity and bandwidth. For a power application like an inverter where you are transmitting power, you want the lowest frequency you can get away with to minimize losses.